# Intersection of uncountable set and countable set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My friend told me that say you have an uncountable set $A$ and a countable set $B$, then the intersection of these two sets is the empty set. But wouldn't something like $A = [0,1]$ and $B = \{1, 2\}$ have the intersection of $\{1\}$? Also is there a way to prove this? Thanks!

Comment: Friends do say some peculiar things....

Comment: Your counterexample is correct.

Comment: With friends like that, you will never need enemies

Comment: Yeah I figured he was wrong so does this also mean that the intersection of countable and uncountable set is always countable? Seems like it should be.

Comment: Yes, you cannot generate an uncountable set from an intersection (subset) of a countable set. It will be countable or empty. *Proof* by contradiction

Comment: Ah, so could I say someting like assume that the intersection of a countable and uncountable set is always uncountable and then just provide the counterexample in my original question?

Comment: That would prove that the intersection is sometimes countable. If you want to challenge yourself, prove that it is always countable. Weirdly, you might have to choose to assume some axioms to make this proof work.

Answer (score 1):

You have disproved your friend's claim.

$A \cap B \subseteq B$.

Hence $A \cap B$ is countable but as you have shown, it need not be empty.

Another counter example would be let $A = \mathbb{R}$ and $B = \mathbb{Q}$, then $A \cap B = \mathbb{Q} \neq \emptyset.$